# Жизненный цикл приложения, Activity

Tags: android

Есть приложение в котором два экрана. Первый экран авторизации (логин-пароль). После прохождения авторизации переходим на второй основной экран. На одном из усторойств (HTC Sense 5), после свораичвания приложения, если запустить приложение заново, то открывается первая активити-авторизации.

Разъясните пожалуйста в чём дело?

Манифест

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

<permission android:name="ru.qwe.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="ru.qwe.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="ru.qwe.activity.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="ru.qwe.activity.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <receiver
        android:name="ru.qwe.receiver.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="ru.qwe" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="ru.qwe.GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```

Comment: покажите свой AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Хм...возможно, вы как-то неправильно перезаписываете методы onPause(), onResume() ? Такое случается только на одном устройстве, на других тестировали?

Comment: Да, только на одном.

Comment: @Nine_slon тогда да, андроид убивает фоновое приложение, как и говорил metalurgus. Я нашел такую статейку [клац](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ram/low-ram.html). Не разбирался, но, возможно, она вам поможет. А так же вот эта [клац](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) На нем нехватает памяти, поэтому система быстро убивает все фоновые приложения.
2) На нем выставлен лимит фоновых процессов в 0.

И еще много разных возможных причин. Но суть остается неизменной: Придется адаптировать свое приложение к таким условиям.

Comment: а как? расскажите ключевые моменты адаптации?